# For a complex sequence $(z_n)$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} z_n =0$ implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |z_n|=0$,?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|z_n|=0$$ this implies that $$|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} z_n|=0,$$ and therefore $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}z_n=0$$ $$\Rightarrow (z_n) \quad \text{is converges to 0=0+0i.}$$

Conversely,

Let $(z_n)$ is converges to 0 i.e., $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}z_n=0$$ does this imply $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|z_n|=0$$

Comment: $z_n$ converging to $0$ implies that both real part and the imaginary part of $z_n$ converge to 0. Use that to get |z_n|$ converge to $0.$

Comment: Does same holds for real sequence

Comment: Yes. Use the epsilon-delta kind of argument. Get your hands dirty, it will follow.

Comment: isn't it the continuity of $|\cdot |$?

Comment: Yes its continuous

Answer (score 1):

$z_n=x_n+iy_n$ converges to $0+i0$ iff $x_n$ converges to $0$ and  $y_n$ converges to $0$ that implies $|z_n|=\sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2}$ converges to $0.$

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be good for your understanding of convergence of sequences if you consider the following problem. A sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ converges to $a$ if and only if the sequence $(a_n-a)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$. Note that this especially implies that from $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$ it directly follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, there is no additional step needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse triangle inequality gives

$$\left| | z_n|- |z|\right| \le | z-z_n|$$

from which your statement immediately follows.